# A String remove all elements in several string set and return the remained string

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string that contains several keyword and is separated by space, and there are several string sets. I write a API to remove all the elements in those string sets from the space-separated string and return the remained space-separated string. And my API is restricted by string input/output type.

For example, input string `S="A B C D E"`, there are two string sets `S1={A,B}, S2={C}`, my API has to remove `A,B,C` from `S` and return `"D E"`.

Here is my code:

```
public String filterString( String keyword, Set<String> set1, String<String> set2 )
{
    // convert string to set in order to remove set
    Set<String> keywordSet = new HashSet<String>( Arrays.asList( keyword.split( "\\s+" ) ) );
    keywordSet.removeAll( set1 );
    keywordSet.removeAll( set2 );

    // convert set to string
    StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer();
    for ( String s : keywordSet )
        strBuf.append( s + " " );
    return strBuf.toString();
}
```

My problem: is there any better or optimal method to rewrite the implementation of my API??

Comment: Looks like a reasonable implementation. Note that `HashSet` doesn't retain order of insertion; I don't know if your resulting string needs the same order as the original string. If it does, you could use `LinkedHashSet`. Also, you might prefer `StringBuilder` over `StringBuffer`.

Comment: I couldn't picture any method being any more optimal. The `removalAll(s)` will take `O(|s|)`. If your two sets can be bigger than your input string, then there are faster algorithms. It depends if you would prefer `O(|S1| + |S2|)` or `O(|keywordSet|)`

Comment: @Cruncher the string set element size is restricted not to be bigger than the input string size splited by the space. So I think my API costs `O(|keywordSet|) - O(|set1|) - O(|set2|)` and no more implementation can be faster than this.

Comment: @EnginePai just to pick at terminology a little bit. There may be a faster implementation but, that doesn't have any less *complexity*. Big O notation measures complexity, not exactly speed. Two different O(n) algorithms can differ greatly with speed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use our friend, Regex, as shown [here](http://ideone.com/FrHNsa).  You'd have to concatenate your sets into the expression in the Pattern.compile argument.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

class Module1{
  public static void main(String[] asd){
  String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
  Pattern re = Pattern.compile("[^ABC\\s+]");
  Matcher m = re.matcher(sourcestring);
  int mIdx = 0;
    while (m.find()){
      for( int groupIdx = 0; groupIdx < m.groupCount()+1; groupIdx++ ){
        System.out.println( "[" + mIdx + "][" + groupIdx + "] = " + m.group(groupIdx));
      }
      mIdx++;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use char[] replace set1 and set2,then keywords toCharArray and foreach equals with before char[] replace ''. Last syso(not '').